# How to equally space 3 divs in one line with equal space from browser

Tags: html, css

Below is my code, here i am placing 3 div's one beside other however i noticed there remains some  space in the right side of the last div. How can  remove it also it should be equally spaced in responsive mode as well.  i want to achieve this without using bootstrap or css grid please help.

```
`
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Responsive Layout</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="row">
        <h1>Our Menu</h1>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <p class="chicken">Chicken</p>
        <div class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut in mauris ut erat iaculis ultricies sit amet sit amet orci. Vestibulum turpis ex, lobortis sed metus quis, egestas vestibulum lectus. Sed nec nulla felis</div></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <p class="beef">Beef</p>
        <div class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut in mauris ut erat iaculis ultricies sit amet sit amet orci. Vestibulum turpis ex, lobortis sed metus quis, egestas vestibulum lectus. Sed nec nulla felis</div></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12">
        <p class="sushi">Sushi</p>
        <div class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut in mauris ut erat iaculis ultricies sit amet sit amet orci. Vestibulum turpis ex, lobortis sed metus quis, egestas vestibulum lectus. Sed nec nulla felis</div></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>`
```

`

```
/********** Base styles **********/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;

}
body{
     font-family: Comic Sans MS, Comic Sans, cursive;
     margin:0;
}
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align:center;
}
section{float:left;margin-right:10px;}

p {
background-color: #A52A2A;
width: 31%;
color: white;
position: relative;
top: -16px;
text-align: center;
float: right;
padding: 5px;
border-top: 0px;
border-bottom: 2px solid black;
border-left: 2px solid black;
border-right: 0px;
}

.desc{
    clear: both;
text-align: left;
top: -16px;
position: relative;
width: 94%;
padding-left: 20px;
height: 108px;
}

/* Simple Responsive Framework. */
.row {
  width: 100%;
}
.col-lg-3{background-color:#959da5; }
.chicken{background-color:#cea0a5;color:black; }
.beef{background-color:#cb2431;}
.sushi{background-color:#ffea7f;color:black; }
/********** Large devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 992px) {

  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 31%;
    margin:11px;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid black;

  }

  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/********** Medium devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

  .col-md-6 {
   width: 46%;
margin: 15px;
float: left;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }

  .col-md-12 {
    width: 96%;
margin: 15px;
  }
  .desc{height: auto;}
}`
```

This is my css please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flexbox` layout as following:

With `flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 0;` you can add as many children as you want and they all will have the same width.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 150px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
}

.child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>


<div class="parent" style="margin-top: 20px;">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>



<div class="parent" style="margin-top: 20px;">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you guide if i can achieve the same with this code instead of flexbox with any few tweaks in my code

Comment: You can change `width: 31%;` property of `col-lg-3` to `width: 33.3%;`

Comment: i tried that but i want spaces in between them not able to achieve that

Comment: You can try to give them `padding` and move the contents to an inner `div`.

Answer (score 1):

give the parent div flex property and it works easy:

```
<div class="parent">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think **Bootstrap** will make this work incredibly easy for you.

**1. just include bootstrap in your HTML, If you don't know how to then google it**

**2. make a div with class row**

**3. Inside the defined div with class row, Make 3 div element with class col-4.**

that's it.

Comment: You can read bootstrap docs on the grid system for more information.